# How to resolve, JSONException: No value for "1"

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

been looking around on the site for a while, and i'm not getting anywhere.

I am creating an android app which is getting a list of values from a mySQL DB via PHP, and returning the result encoded in a JSON object:

```
{"error":false,"values":{"1":{"name":"This is a string"}, "2":{...}}}
```

I am retrieving the JSON object in java like so:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

if (!error) {
    JSONObject values = jObj.getJSONObject("values");
    Iterator<?> keys = values.keys();

    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        JSONObject value = jObj.getJSONObject(key);
        ...
    }
```

Its at the point before the ellipses where I get the exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for "1"
```

Am I doing something completely stupid, or what, everything looks ok to me. I have tried multiple different things but keep getting the same issue.
What i would ultimately like to do is get the name obj and add it to a List of strings. But I can't seem to get beyond this point.

Any help or push in the right direction would be grateful.

Comment: Should you read value using __values.getJSONObject(key)__ and not from __jObj__.

Comment: Do you have access over PHP api to get the data? Because it's better to make values as Array instead of Object so you can iterate over it easily.

Comment: i have posted soltion please try it.

Comment: @AlokPatel I do, and ill give it a try, cheers for the tip...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject value = jObj.getJSONObject(key);
```

Replace with

```
JSONObject value = values.getJSONObject(key);
```

Comment: I feel Like an idiot.. Cheers for returning my sanity :)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

if (!error) {
    JSONObject values = jObj.getJSONObject("values");
    Iterator<?> keys = values.keys();

    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        JSONObject value = values.getJSONObject(key);
        ...
    }
```